# How to set background color of PsiFileNode or its child

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How to set background color of PsiFileNode or its child?
I know how to change PsiFileNode fileName foreground

```
    public class MarkedFile extends PsiFileNode {
    private Color backgroundColor;

    public MarkedFile(Project project, @NotNull PsiFile value, ViewSettings viewSettings, Color backgroundColor) {
        super(project, value, viewSettings);
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public Color getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    protected PresentationData createPresentation() {
        PresentationData presentationData = super.createPresentation();
        presentationData.setForcedTextForeground(backgroundColor);
        return presentationData;
    }
  }
```

But how to set **background** color of file as we can see it in "target" or "out" java directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the background color of files in the project tree and tabs via `EditorTabColorProvider.EP_NAME` extension point. Override `getProjectViewColor` to highlight a file in the project tree.

Answer (score 1):

The background color of nodes in the tree view is controlled by file colors (Settings | Appearance and Behavior | File Colors). There is no way to override the background color for an individual node.

Comment: Is there a way to override the background color for a directory? Can I access to the Apperance settings by code?

Comment: The file color settings apply to both files and directories. See the other answer for the correct way to override this.